# How do I make a map that when changing the state does not modify all the elements - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a json with several values, one of them is "iframe" which can be "si" (yes) or "no" depending on whether it is an iframe or not.
With that value (yes / no) I need `(this.props.tabsiframe === 'yes')` to show an `<iframe>` or a `<div>`.

My code works, because if `(this.props.tabsiframe === 'yes')` is an iframe it paints an iframe, but if the next element is `(this.props.tabsiframe === 'no' )` change all the elements of `<iframe>` to `<div>`.

The re-rendering changes the already created divs and converts them to iframe if iframe = yes and if it is = it does not change the iframe to div. This is an example of what happens
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cY9eHq_aBuQb8b_HtYUXjC6lqrYCJe3p/view

Maybe it happens because every time I click on the element the menu is updated: `divIframe: {tabsDivIframe: [... new Set (this.state.divIframe.tabsDivIframe), url] .filter (function (el) { return the;})},`. A new url is added to the array, so I guess that's what it renders and it changes the divs to iframes or iframes to divs.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);

        ["openTabs", "removeTab"].forEach((method) => {
            this[method] = this[method].bind(this);
        });

        this.state = {
            tabs:{
                tabsLi: [],    
            },
            divIframe:{
                tabsDivIframe: [],
            },
            tabsiframe : '',
            showtabs: true,
        }
    }

    openTabs(e, url, iframe, trdtitle){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            showtabs: false,
        })
        if (this.state.tabs.tabsLi.includes(trdtitle) === false){
            this.setState({
                tabs: { tabsLi:[...new Set(this.state.tabs.tabsLi),trdtitle].filter(function(el) { return el; })},
                divIframe: { tabsDivIframe:[...new Set(this.state.divIframe.tabsDivIframe),url].filter(function(el) { return el; })},
                tabsiframe: iframe,
            }, () => {
                console.log(this.state.tabs.tabsLi);console.log(this.state.divIframe.tabsDivIframe);console.log(this.state.tabsiframe)
            })
        }
}
render(){
        return (
            <><Tabs
                       showtabs={this.state.showtabs}
                        tabs={this.state.tabs}
                        tabsLi={this.state.tabs.tabsLi}
                        divIframe={this.state.divIframe}
                        tabsDivIframe={this.state.divIframe.tabsDivIframe}
                        tabsiframe={this.state.tabsiframe}
                        openTabs={this.openTabs}
                        removeTab={this.removeTab}
                    />
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

```
class Tabs extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div id="content-tabs" className="tabs">
            {( this.props.showtabs)  
                ? (
                    <>
                    <div className="waiting-leads">
                        <p>Parece que todavía no hay ningún lead...</p>
                        <h3>¡Ánimo, ya llega!</h3>
                        <img src={imgDinosaurio} alt="Dinosaurio"></img>
                    </div>
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        <DivAndIframe
                            tabsDivIframe={this.props.divIframe.tabsDivIframe}
                            tabsiframe={this.props.tabsiframe}
                        />
                    </>
            )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class DivAndIframe extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <>
            {this.props.tabsDivIframe.map((url, index) =>
                <div key={url.toString() id={"myTab" + index}>
                {( this.props.tabsiframe === 'si')
                    ? (
                        <iframe title={"iframe"+index} className="iframeTab" src={url}></iframe>

                    ) : (
                        <div>{url}</div>
                )}
                </div>
            )}   
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is re-rendering a problem? Have you tried using something different than `index` as `key`?

Comment: Yes, the re-rendering is the problem. Change the elements already created. And no, I have not tried to use anything other than the index. Do you think that may be the problem?

Comment: Maybe. Using `index` should be a "last resort" as described in https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
You also use `index` in `iframe[title]`, so this might trigger re-rendering.

Comment: im a bit confused here: "this.props.tabsiframe === 'si'" doesn't change per iteration of map, so all of your mapped items will either all be iframes or all be div

Comment: I think that's not the problem, because I've changed it and it's still happening. My problem is that an element is a ``<iframe>`` and when I do the re-render if the value of ``iframe`` (json value) is "not" the new element that it creates and the ``iframe`` previous are changed to ``div``

Comment: @ leo I think that's the problem. But I do not know how to make those who are iframe continue to be and those who are div remain

Comment: how does tabsDivIframe look?

Comment: @leo I have added the parent class of DivAndIframe where it is represented

Comment: @Casandra Check out this fiddle and see if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/43tqnewf/
basically, for each mapped item you need a boolean to say if it is an iframe or not. I'm not sure how your objects look, so i defined one in the component as a sample

Comment: @leo that is not my problem. When doing the re-rendering it changes the divs already created and converts them to iframe if ``iframe = si`` and if it is ``iframe = no`` does not change the iframe to div [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cY9eHq_aBuQb8b_HtYUXjC6lqrYCJe3p/view)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having here is within your map. 
Here is a state map to try to explain:

After First tab Click (div):

- this.props.tabsiframe = 'no'
- this.props.tabsDivIframe = ['www.sampleurl1.com']

After Second tab Click (iframe):

- this.props.tabsiframe = 'yes'
- this.props.tabsDivIframe = ['www.iframe2.com', 'www.sampleurl1.com']

so on the virtual DOM after the second click, the map will again iterate through this.props.tabDivIframe and evaluate this.props.tabsiframe as 'si' or 'no' for everything.

```
{this.props.tabsDivIframe.map((url, index) =>
    <div key={url.toString() id={"myTab" + index}>
    {( this.props.tabsiframe === 'si') //this line here; we share this same value for all tabs
        ? (
            <iframe title={"iframe"+index} className="iframeTab" src={url}></iframe>
        ) : (
            <div>{url}</div>
    )}
    </div>
)}
```

I wrote a small interactive sample of your problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/eojrx6my/6/
You will need to store individual 'tabsiframe' for each url, or somehow identify them individually

Comment: Indeed that is my problem. And can you think of a way to do it? Can you give me an idea? Thank you